# How do I dimension the natural frequency formula?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

with masses declared as grams and static stiffness as N/mm, how do I dimension them for Hz ?

Comment: Homework?  What have you done so far?  If you write out the differential equation for a vibrating assembly, how do the mass and stiffness show up?

Comment: What are the units in N ?

Comment: Mike I don't understand your question

Comment: What do you multiply to get Newtons...

Comment: multiply from what to Newtons Mike ?

Comment: @FabioSpaghetti I remember that mass * gravity = Newtons... So all you need now is some dimensional analysis...

Comment: @SolarMike "I remember that mass * gravity = Newtons" You remember wrong. Mass * acceleration of ONE m/s^2 =  Newtons.

Comment: @alephzero so if it is 2 m/s^2 it won’t be Newtons...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Units of N, mm (for the stiffness k), and g (for the mass m) are not consistent. You need to convert these values to use in the basic equation for the frequency: $$f=\frac{1}{2*\pi} \sqrt \frac{k}{m}$$ Knowing that $1 \, N = 1 \, kg*m/s^2$, $1 \, m = 1000 \, mm$, and $1 \, kg = 1000 \, g$, you get the following:
$$f=\frac{1}{2*\pi} \sqrt \frac{N/mm*((1 kg*m/s^2)/N)*(1000 mm/m)}{g*(1 kg/1000 g)}$$
All of the units cancel except for $\sqrt {1/s^2}$. Doing the math gives the following result:
$$f = \frac{1000}{2*\pi} \sqrt \frac{k \; in \; N/mm}{m \; in \; g}$$
where f is in units of cycles/sec = Hz.

Comment: You don't have to convert everything into basic SI units, any consistent set of units will do. If the OP wants to use N, mm, and Hz (i.e. seconds) then in "F=ma" you increase the measure of acceleration by a factor of 1000 changing from m to mm, so you need to decrease the measure of mass by 1000, i.e. measure it in Mg not kg. The engineering company I work for uses exactly that set of units, which conveniently give pressure in MPa. Of course density is in the slightly weird units of megagrams per cubic millimeter, but it's easy to remember that just means "specific gravity $\times10^{-9}$"

Comment: … and forgetting the $10^{-9}$ gives answers that are so completely wrong that nobody would ever believe them, which is the best sort of error to make!

Answer (score -1):

One Newton is equal to 101.971grams and one gram is 0.00980665N.
In free undamped vibration we have to convert grams to Newtons,

$$  \omega_n = \sqrt \frac{k}{0.00980665*m_{grams}}$$

$$  T= \frac{2\pi}{\omega_n} $$
$$  f_n=\frac{1}{T}= \frac{\omega_n}{2\pi}$$

**Edit**

Going over my answer after @John answer, I realize that I was wrong. I leave my answer should it be an example of how you can be wrong.

Comment: Force is not mass. This is just nonsense.

Comment: @alephzero, I don't know what you mean. I am  just using a constant.

Comment: Thank you Kamran, I was rather searching to dimension analysis for this formula

Comment: @FabioSpaghetti, I'm glad to be able to help.

Comment: @Kamran I agree with alephzero that your equation is incorrect. I am not sure where you got 1 N = 101.971 g.  I have posted a new answer.

Comment: @alephzero I see that John Hiltz went down the garden path multiplying mass by gravity in his solution to get Newtons...

Comment: @SolarMike Not at all, "g" means "grams" not "gravity". But we now have a correct answer accepted, which is the main thing.

Comment: @kamran You don't seem to understand the difference between customary USA units (where "g" can appear in these formulas of you measure both mass and force in "pounds") and SI units (where it does not).